# T-SQL Update trigger with multiple rows

Tags: t-sql, triggers

Consider a trigger `after update` on the table A.
For every update the trigger should update all the records in table B.
Then consider this query:

```
UPDATE A SET X = Y
```

Apparently there are many rows updated. After the update the trigger takes place.
Now if the trigger would be using `inserted` table, and you would like to update the table B with every single row of the temporary table `inserted`, and in MSDN is not recommended to use cursors, how would you do that?

Thank you

Comment: You need to post the structure of both tables and how they relate to each other in order to get an accurate answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what exactly you want to do in your update trigger, but you could e.g.

```
UPDATE dbo.B
SET someColumn = i.Anothervalue
FROM Inserted i
WHERE b.Criteria = i.Criteria
```

or something else - you need to tell us a bit more about what it is you want to do with table B! But it's definitely possible to update, insert into or other things, without using a cursor and handling multiple rows from the `Inserted` table.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to know.. i can match it with all rows from the inserted table.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that table A is related to table B via a key (have to assume, as you posted no details).

If that is the case, you can use either sub-queries or joins with `inserted` to select the rows that need changing on table B.

```
UPDATE tableB B
SET B.colx = someValue
WHERE B.id IN
(
    SELECT b_id 
    FROM INSERTED
)
```